# Cannot boot to windows after installing linux mint

Tags: linux-mint, boot, windows, dual-boot, grub

I have installed linux mint to my external SSD on my surface pro 3. During the installation I touched only the external drive, and chose it also on the option 'device for boot loader installation' at the end. I finished the installation and booted and it worked perfectly. 
however after removing the external SSD and booting from internal, instead of windows boot I get GNU grub Minimal bash like editing line screen. 
how can i fix this?

edit: I hope very much that I didn't delete anything on the main drive. seems to me very unlikely. I ran fdisk -l and it looks like everything there.

Answer (score 0):

after researching from various different sources, I managed to learn a bit about the boot process, the BCD store and grub. I found a solution.

I learned that grub mbr, the sort of stage 1 grub was installed on the main internal disk (C:). however stage 2 was written on the external one (say E:). Grub was unable to find its stage 2 when E was disconnected and therefore the error. now:

1.typing `exit` assured me that windows boot manager was ok. 
2. on the cmd, I typed `bcdedit /set {fwbootmgr} displayorder {bootmgr} /addfirst` and that made the windows boot manager appear before the grub. I must say that before that I tried `bootrec /fixmbr & bootrec /fixboot & bootrec /rebuildcbd` But that was unhelpful, as it didn't touch the grub installation.

Now the surface boots directly into windows. But thats not the full solution, since I want linux as well. I actually understood that I need grub on my C drive since surface is unable to boot from an external SSD without some hard work done. My mistake was apparently, that I chose to install the grub files on the external disk. The solution should be re-installing it on the main disk, so I would be able to see the menu, hopefully it will let me choose between linux/windows when E: is connected and windows when its not.
that belongs however to a different topic. I am lazy as for now :) (could just leave it be, typing exit when I want windows to boot. but sometimes I am without the keyboard, using it as a windows tablet).